# How to change a char to an integer?

Tags: c, char, type-conversion

I would like to copy the contents of a char array to int variables or an array. For example, the first five values have to go to an int array (int x):

```
char a[] = "123456";
```

I saw in other threads that to change a char to an int, I need to do this:

```
int x = a[0] - '0';
```

Is there other ways of doing it?

What if I wanted to the values in groups of two or more, such as 12, 34 and 56?

And what if I didn't what to save them as ints, but floats or other types instead?

Comment: your question is requesting too much. It would be possible to do everything you want to accomplish, but you would need to write some code for each task. The most generic you could get is to use a Union.

Comment: you can always [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html), eg `char a[] = "123456"; int b, c, d; sscanf(a, "%2d%3d%d", &b, &c, &d); printf("b=%d; c=%d; d=%d\n", b, c, d);`

Comment: @pmg But why would you do that as long as `strtol()` and `strtod()` are available?

Comment: @H2 because with scanf you can give lengths and turn the thing into 12, 34, 56 in one operation.

Comment: @H2CO3: see my edit. There may be reasons to avoid copying the digits arounds. With `sscanf()` you can limit the conversion to 2 or 3 or whatever digits.

Comment: @pmg Hm, I think I see your point. (I'm still a bit afraid of the `scanf()` family of functions, they at best aren't obvious to use so they're easier to abuse.)

Comment: @H2CO3: I agree copying the digits around and using `strtol()` or similar is better. I also agree `scanf()` is hard to use correctly (my example is incorrect by being too simple).

Comment: @pmg (Honestly, I can't even decide if your example is correct :))

Comment: @H2CO3: you can see my example (with an extra check) at [ideone](http://ideone.com/PRsnH1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy properly sized portions of the string to a separate buffer and use [`strtol()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/strtol.html) or [`strtod()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtod.html).

Comment: @pmg Thanks, I'm lazy :P By the way, you could have posted your solution using `sscanf()`.

Comment: Like you said in comments, `sscanf()` is hard to use correctly. I feel safer (from copy/paste programmers that end up writing code for the airplane I flow in to take my next vacations) with your answer than with mine.

Comment: @pmg That's wise, indeed. (Too bad there are copy-paste programmers.)

Answer (score 1):

You are on write track, however if you want to convert into integer array then you 
should use something like

```
int x[MAX_ELEM];

for(int i =0; i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(char); i++)
{
   x[i] = a[i] -'0';
}
```

For other cases you will need to deal separately.

Comment: And for your information, `sizeof(char)` is always `1`, so you don't even need to speel it out.

Comment: Yes it is not required. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you have to do `int x = a[0] - '0';` is because of the character encoding in C.  What is happening is you are subtracting the encoding offset from the character.  Here is a table with all the encoding values: [UTF-8 encodings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout).  So `int x = a[0] - '0';` is equivalent in your case to `int x = 49 - 48;` which has the correct value you were looking for.  By using `'0'` instead of `0` you are using the char value of 0.

There are other ways of doing it, but this way works well.  To use other types, just do type casting after you create the `int`.

John's way of getting two digit numbers works well.  Reposted here, it was `number = 10 * digit1 + digit2`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

- Sure, there are other ways of doing it.  The way you've shown converts the ASCII value to the digit it represents, but there are other ways.
- Read in the number of characters you want, convert each character to a digit, and construct the integer from those digits like `number = 10 * digit1 + digit2`.
- Do type casting after you construct the integers.